# Why cloud build saying I am missing Required 'compute.instances.create' permission for my project?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-build, google-cloud-iam, cloudbuild.yaml

I am trying to use the "create with container" method but getting the following error :

> ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.create-with-container) Could not
> fetch resource: Step #2:  - Required 'compute.instances.create'
> permission for
> 'projects/local_test_prod1283/zones/us-central1-a/instances/instanceapptraining'

I checked and the project local_test_prod1283 **does have** role `compute.instanceAdmin.v1`

My cloud buil yaml below :

```
steps:
- name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
  args: ['build', '-t', 'gcr.io/local_test_prod1283/apptraining', '.']

- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: ["push", "gcr.io/local_test_prod1283/apptraining"]

- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  args: ['compute', 'instances', 'create-with-container', 'instanceapptraining', '--machine-type=n1-standard-1', '--zone=us-central1-a', '--preemptible', '--container-image=gcr.io/local_test_prod1283/apptraining']
```

What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 3):

Nevermind, i had to add the compute.instanceAdmin.v1 to the @cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use Cloud Shell:

```
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding $PROJECT --role roles/compute.instances.create --member='serviceAccount:test-proj1@@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com'
```

Comment: This answer is wrong but you are on the right track. The role must be added to the Cloud Build service account which ends in **@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com**.

Comment: Thanks @JohnHanley, may I edit the answer ?

Comment: Yes, of course. Improvements are always welcome.